# Is it okay to have more than one ":root" selector?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

In TWBS 4, bootstrap.css has a **:root** selector with color variables.

Can my **child stylesheet** *also* have a `:root` selector, for my own variables?

I'm guessing `:root {}` can be overridden and added to like any other selector, but I haven't been able to find any discussion or example of it.

So far, I've put my color variables in a **div {}** selector and it works, but I want to apply them to elements besides `<div>`, so it seems I should have my own `:root` section.

This works:

**my_stylesheet.css**

```
div {
  --myColor1: rgba(16, 128, 0, 1.0);
  --myColor2: rgba(16, 128, 0, 0.6);
}
```

but I'd like to do this:

```
:root {
  --myColor1: rgba(16, 128, 0, 1.0);
  --myColor2: rgba(16, 128, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: [`:` **r** `oot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) ?

Comment: Good eye -- typo. Should be **:root**.  I've edited it.  Thanks for confirming that it's just an "ordinary selector" in your comment in your answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`:root` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) represents the `<html>` tag and has a higher specificity (priority) than `html` selector. This selector is commonly used to declare CSS variables. Other than that, you may treat `:root` as any common selector -- multiple selectors in any valid combinations.

Comment: Oops, I've corrected the typo.  I meant, can there be more than one `:root` selector defined?

Comment: I might be wrong but doesn't `:root` also select the top level of a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) if used from a `<style>` or `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag within a [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)?

Comment: @Genki sure it's like any common selector.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts kinda sounds like [`:host()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host())?