# I want to switch one of three, matching a identifier for `:root` with class when I check one of radio buttons only in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-variables

I wanted to write a pure CSS and HTML, without JavaScript, to switch more than two themes. I was inspired by the [article about unlimited theme switcher](https://alexandersandberg.com/articles/creating-a-website-theme-switcher-with-css-only/), but our cases are different.

- I use class with theme name for HTML root;
- I added class regular expression prefix with a theme name, together with a input radio or label identifier;
- I added a class with theme name for the `html` element.

If possible, keep the original HTML `:root` part in CSS, but you can modify another part of identifiers, but if you think it is impossible, let me know.

Here is the small code:

```css
:root[class*="voxel-theme-light"], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-]) {
  --color-primary: #000;
  --color-secondary: #fff;
}

:root[class*="voxel-theme-dark"], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-]) {
  --color-primary: #fff;
  --color-secondary: #000;
}

:root[class*="voxel-theme-tomato"], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-]) {
  --color-primary: #fff;
  --color-secondary: #ff6347;
}

[class="voxel-theme-light"] #theme-switch1:checked~#page {
  --text: var(--color-primary);
  --background: var(--color-secondary);
}

[class="voxel-theme-dark"] #theme-switch2:checked~#page {
  --text: var(--color-primary);
  --background: var(--color-secondary);
}

[class="voxel-theme-tomato"] #theme-switch3:checked~#page {
  --text: var(--color-primary);
  --background: var(--color-secondary);
}

body, #page
{
  color: var(--text);
  background-color: var(--background);
}

.theme-switch {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

.switch-label {
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: var(--text);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 125%;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  transition: box-shadow .2s, border .2s;
}
```

And small HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="voxel-theme-light">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/test.css">
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" class="theme-switch" name="theme-switch" id="theme-switch1">
  <label for="theme-switch1" class="switch-label">Light</label>
  <input type="radio" class="theme-switch" name="theme-switch" id="theme-switch2">
  <label for="theme-switch2" class="switch-label">Dark</label>
  <input type="radio" class="theme-switch" name="theme-switch" id="theme-switch3">
  <label for="theme-switch3" class="switch-label">Tomato</label>

  <div id="page">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, consequuntur.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I expected, that I was able to check one of three radios to switch, render or display the theme, but as a result, nothing happened.

#### Update 1

> Also, where is `--text` and `--background` declared?

Observe that

```css
body, #page
{
  color: var(--text);
  background-color: var(--background);
}
```

that comes from:

```css
[class="voxel-theme-light"] #theme-switch1:checked~#page {
  --text: var(--color-primary);
  --background: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

that comes finally from:

```css
:root[class*="voxel-theme-light"], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-]) {
  --color-primary: #000;
  --color-secondary: #fff;
}
```

> Also, `:root[class*="voxel-theme-dark"], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-])` makes very little sense.

It is not my code, it is my company's developers' code. They did this code. It comes bundled with an Angular library of Node.js. Their themes files are in SCSS.

If I didn't keep the original `:root` part, my file will be outdated, as my company's developers will update the themes tokens files weekly or monthly.

Of course, that I would import easily their SCSS files in one SCSS with only the identifiers part. But I need to figure out how to match to the identifiers or just use the SCSS variables for a different `:root` as you have suggested.

> Also, if you aren't using any JavaScript how do you change the class on  tag?

It is true. You are right. It is possible only with JavaScript.

I wanted to share my Markdown project with my colleagues and design developers for Confluence articles with their company's segment theme look that they want. The enterprise version of Confluence doesn't allow us to add JavaScript extension or to insert JavaScript code or to unsanitise JavaScript codes in an HTML formatting macro. Of course, I will include JavaScript files on my project, but only for their GitHub/GitLab documentation sites, their sites, their one-single self-contained HTML page for article, thesis, and tutorial. It is why I will separate the different Confluence, Codebraid and Pandoc YAML files for different frameworks.

#### Update 2

> I believe your developer is confused or you copied something wrong or left something out.

I copied correctly and didn't leave anything out. I wish I print my company's project source code to show you it, but the company does not allow uploading the image here, but they allow me to copy and paste their project's small source code only if there's a bug. They also allow me to tell how their project is like. Allow me to explain and show their project tree at the end.

My developers are not confused. They just made a **bad** code.

You can check my correct and original CSS code on my another question in which I copied the small source from my company's project:

[Adding a theme (one of three themes) when you switch, and a mode (dark or light) when you toggle, to a HTML element in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955471/adding-a-theme-one-of-three-themes-when-you-switch-and-a-mode-dark-or-light)

Of course, Anton gave me the clean and good theme name class that you also gave, but I need to apply the whole HTML (`html`), not just `body` and `#page` because of Confluence and of VSCode's and Codebraid's Markdown Preview. Observe that that included JavaScript code is only for their documentation sites and HTML files.

Now I'll explain and show their project tree:

```
node_modules/@voxel/tokens
├── ion
│   ├── tokens.css
│   ├── tokens.d.ts
│   ├── tokens-icon.css
│   ├── tokens-icon.scss
│   ├── tokens.js
│   └── tokens.scss
├── iti
│   ├── tokens.css
│   ├── tokens.d.ts
│   ├── tokens-icon.css
│   ├── tokens-icon.scss
│   ├── tokens.js
│   └── tokens.scss
├── tokens.scss
├── tokens-themes.d.ts
├── tokens-themes.js
└── varejo
    ├── tokens.css
    ├── tokens.d.ts
    ├── tokens-icon.css
    ├── tokens-icon.scss
    ├── tokens.js
    └── tokens.scss
```

It's developed for Angular projects with their company components library (for example, `@voxel/components`, that will use `@voxel/tokens`). The `ion`, `iti` and `varejo` are segments themes names; all the almost `tokens` files in both CSS and SCSS have all same CSS variable but with different colours. Each one of all these files also has only **one** `:root` that also is the same `:root[class*="voxel-theme-light"], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-])`.

I copy the complete code of a `tokens` file in CSS format to my file, to keep it updated. The different is that my same file will have **all** their tokens `:root`s in.

#### Update 3

I am at my company's computer. I am copying a small sample from developers' project's few files:

- `node_modules/@voxel/tokens/ion/tokens.css`:

```css
:root[class*="voxel-theme-ion"], :root:not([class*="voxel-theme-"]) {
--ids_color_action_primary_base: #133134;
--ids_color_action_primary_base_soft: rgba(19, 49, 52, 0.1);
--ids_color_action_primary_base_medium: rgba(19, 49, 52, 0.5);
--ids_color_action_primary_base_strong: rgba(19, 49, 52, 0.8);
}
```

- `node_modules/@voxel/tokens/ion/tokens.scss`:

```scss
$ids_color_action_primary_base: #133134;
$ids_color_action_primary_base_soft: rgba(19, 49, 52, 0.1);
$ids_color_action_primary_base_medium: rgba(19, 49, 52, 0.5);
$ids_color_action_primary_base_strong: rgba(19, 49, 52, 0.8);
```

- `node_modules/@voxel/tokens/iti/tokens.css`:

```css
:root[class*="voxel-theme-iti"], :root:not([class*="voxel-theme-"]) {
--ids_color_action_primary_base: #FE3386;
--ids_color_action_primary_base_soft: rgba(254, 51, 134, 0.1);
--ids_color_action_primary_base_medium: rgba(254, 51, 134, 0.5);
--ids_color_action_primary_base_strong: rgba(254, 51, 134, 0.8);
}
```

- `node_modules/@voxel/tokens/iti/tokens.scss`:

```scss
--ids_color_action_primary_base: #FE3386;
--ids_color_action_primary_base_soft: rgba(254, 51, 134, 0.1);
--ids_color_action_primary_base_medium: rgba(254, 51, 134, 0.5);
--ids_color_action_primary_base_strong: rgba(254, 51, 134, 0.8);
```

Comment: @somethinghere `:root` is `html` with a higher priority. It can be used like any other selector multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788085/2813224

Comment: If you aren't using any JavaScript how do you change the class on `<html>` tag?

Comment: `[class="voxel-theme-light"]` is a horrible selector use `.voxel-theme-light` instead. Also, `:root[class*="voxel-theme-dark"], :root:not([class^=voxel-theme-]) `  makes very little sense. Simply `:root.voxel-theme-dark` should suffice. Also, post your code as a [mcve]

Comment: Please read my update. I apologise for long explanations.

Comment: I edited my comment upon seeing how `--text` and `--background` is declared. I never used per-processors like SCSS but I can't possibly imagine to what purpose `:root:not([class^=voxel-theme-])` would actually serve.  `:root[class*="voxel-theme-dark"]` means that anytime the `<html>` tag has a className with "voxel-theme-dark" anywhere in it is a match, so a className of "voxel-theme-dark-makes-no-sense" or makes-no-sense voxel-theme-dark" matches. Then followed by  `:root:not([class^=voxel-theme-])` which means: *match anything EXCEPT a className that starts with: "voxel-theme-" so {Cont...)

Comment: (Cont.) "voxel-theme-dark-makes-no-sense" wouldn't match but "makes-no-sense" would match. Each one of those bad selectors is separated by a comma so it it's like `selector1 OR selector2`. So the third set selector2 will always override selector2 on the first and second sets. I believe your developer is confused or you copied something wrong or left something out.

Comment: As my explanation about their project and its tree is long, but detailed. I added the update. Please read `Update 2`. You'll understand.

Comment: @zer00ne, I am at company's computer now. I have just copied small samples from company's developers' project CSS and SCSS files at `Update 3`. Also check the project tree that I have just updated at `Update 2` end.

Comment: There's [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has). However it is very new and has limited support. Firefox doesn't yet support it and VSCode may be using an older engine and so may not support it.